# Django and Celery error when using RabbitMQ in Centos "[Errno 111] Connection Refused"

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I'm using Django and Celery with RabbitMQ as the message broker. While developing in Windows I installed RabbitMQ and configured Celery inside Django like this:

celery.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'main.settings')

app = Celery('DjangoExample')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

**init**.py

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

When running Celery inside my development Windows machine everything works correctly and tasks are being executed as expected.

Now I'm trying to deploy the app inside a Centos7 machine.
I installed RabbitMQ and I tried running Celery with the following command:

```
celery -A main worker -l INFO
```

But I get a "connection refused" error:

```
[2021-02-24 17:39:58,221: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
```

I don't have any special configuration for Celery inside my settings.py since it was working fine in Windows without it.

You can find the settings.py here:
https://github.com/adrenaline681/DjangoExample/blob/master/main/settings.py

Here is a screenshot of the celery error:

[image]

And here is the status of my RabbitMQ Server that shows that it's currently installed and running.

[image]

Here is an image of the RabbitMQ Management Plugin web interface, we you can see the port used for amqp:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?
How can I get Celery to work correctly with RabbitMQ inside of Centos7?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: please share `settings.py`.

Comment: @Chandan I've added a link to the settings.py in github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem and it was SELinux blocking access between those two processes, I mean RabbitMQ and Python. To check my guess please disable selinux temporarily and check if it goes ok. And if it is ok then you have to configure selinux to grant access Python to connect Rabbitmq. To disable SELinux temporarily you can run in shell

`# setenforce 0`

See more [here](https://www.tecmint.com/disable-selinux-in-centos-rhel-fedora/) about disabling SELinux either temporarily or permanently. But actually I would not recommend disabling SELinux. Actually it is better to configure SELinux to grant access. See more about SELinux [here](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/linux/what-is-selinux).

Answer (score 1):

You said you are developing on Windows but you showed some outputs that look like Linux.  Are you using Docker or some other container?

I don't know if you are using Docker or some other containers but you can likely adapt my advice to your setup.

If you are using docker you'll have need to have Django's settings.py configured to docker container running RabbitMQ instead of 127.0.0.1.  The URL you provided for your settings.py file doesn't work so I cannot see what you have in there.

Here's my CELERY_... settings:

```
# Celery settings
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://user:TheUserName@rabbitmq'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://redis:6379/'
```

I set it to the name I use for my container_name hosting each service because my docker-compose file has these:

```
  services:
    rabbitmq:
      ...
      container_name: rabbitmq
    redis:
      ...
      container_name: redis
```